# How to ensure integrity in SQL schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit of a design dilemma in SQL - and not being very experienced would appreciate some suggestions as tohow best to tackle this:

Here's what I have so far:

- ProductGroupMinor has a 1-1 relationship with ProductGroupMajor
- A bridge table allows a Category to have 1 or more ProductGroupMajor's
- Offer table has an ID for category and ProductGroupMinor

The bit that I'm struggling with is how to ensure that the **Category**/**ProductGroupMinor** combination is a valid one.

[image]

Comment: can you include a simple table structure? Its not clear from your question whether Offer, OfferTypeMinor, OfferTypeMajor etc are tables or columns...

Comment: For clarity they'e colums in the offer table

Comment: @StevieG - schema added

Comment: Your shema and your question use different wording. ProductGroup=OfferType?  Please clarify.

Comment: @serg - Sorry, I replaced a conceptual image with a proper schema - I forgot to check I was using the same language. All should now be correct

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that your definition of 'valid' is: a combination of `Category/ProductGroupMinor` is valid if a combination of `Category/ProductGroupMajor' exists where `ProductGroupMajor' is the parent of ProductGroupMinor, and Category is the same ?

Comment: @StevieG - yes - that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but be aware of drawbacks.

Namely, you can declare  ProductGroupMinor (ID+ ProductGroupMajorID) being UK which is totally correct, it is unique. Then point FK from Offer to this UK and migrate  ProductGroupMajorID to the Offer. And now declare Offer (CategoryID+ ProductGroupMajorID) FK to  ProductGroupMajor_Category bridge table. This will give you bullet-proof referencial integrity. For example, no one can now delete something from bridge table while this combination is referenced in some Offer.

But it will aslo place a burden on developers to keep track of those extra relationships. For example if you need rearange  Product Groups, i.e. to change  ProductGroupMajorID in  ProductGroupMinor, it must be a transaction involving a number of tables and a number of checks.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and advice. I take on board what you say about the extra maintenance, but what would you do if you had to make same decision?

Comment: It depends on your system architecture. I saw a number of big ERPs where SQL has no RI at all, integrity was enforced by special business rule tier. The reason was there are many rules in big system and DB's RI is only a small fraction of them. So why support two set of rules?